# Software to strip image of any metadata

Tags: images, privacy, metadata

A concern I often have when sharing pictures online is that there may be some metadata contained within that will compromise my privacy. [Exif data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Privacy_and_security) is one such example.

How can I strip any such information from an image which would then allow me to upload pictures worry free? (I only refer to metadata, because of course there could be revealing information in the actual image)

Comment: Software questions like this are off topic. I've edited your question to keep it on topic, if you don't like it, you can roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like [ExifTool](http://download.cnet.com/ExifTool/3000-2193_4-10791213.html)

> ExifTool is a platform-independent command-line application for
>   reading, writing, and editing Meta information that is contained by
>   image, audio and video files. It extracts thumbnail images, preview
>   images, and large JPEG images from RAW files, copies meta information
>   between files, reads or writes structured XMP information, deletes
>   meta information individually, in groups, or altogether, and sets the
>   file modification date from EXIF information.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools available for that task, for example you can consider [JPEG & PNG Stripper](http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=30) (freeware):

> A tool for stripping/cleaning/removing uncessary metadata (junk) from
>   JPG/JPEG/JFIF & PNG files. The image quality IS NOT AFFECTED. Includes
>   command line support. Just specify a folder or file on the commandline
>   (wildcards allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has a nice feature allowing you to remove properties and personal information from files.

In order to do this all you have to do is the following:

Select all files/photos you wish to strip of their info then right click one of the selected items.
in the context menu click Properties and then go to the Details tab.
at the bottom you should see a link named "Remove Properties and Personal Information". click it.
the rest is pretty much straightforward...

Comment: Works on Windows 11 as well.